# R - ggplot maximum tick grouped by runnumber Netlogo

Tags: r, netlogo

I have a small problem. I have the output of Netlogo in an R dataframe. 
Now I would like to plot the maximum number of ticks of each Run over the Runnumber.
So I have one column that is called 'tick' and one that is called 'runNumber'. And I would like to plot the maximum of 'tick' over the different runNumbers.

I hope you can help me,

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely an issue of how to deal with your data in R and since it offers you countless ways to achieve what you ask, I'll just show you one possible method:

Some sample data to work with:

```
df <- data.frame(tick = c(1:10, 1:35, 1:17),
                 runNumber = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 35), rep(3, 17)))
```

You can see that the maximum number of ticks in each of the three runs is 10, 35 and 17, respectively.
In order to plot those, you need to manipulate your data (I suggest you read up on `dplyr` in its [vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html)):

```
library(dplyr)

df.summary <- df %>%
  group_by(runNumber) %>%
  summarise(max_tick = max(tick))

df.summary
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#   runNumber max_tick
# 1         1       10
# 2         2       35
# 3         3       17
```

The `dplyr` code is rather self-explanatory. You treat each run as a separate group and only extract the maximum of the `tick` column.

To visualize this data you could simply use:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df.summary, aes(x = runNumber, y = max_tick)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```